# Mi sistema no reconoce el escritorio de mi equipo para leer archivos en python

Tags: python, consola

[[image: Intento que la consola reconozca una carpeta en mi escritorio pero ni siquiera se sitúa ahí.]

La verdad no conozco nada de programación. Espero alguien ayudarme, creo que tiene que ver con One Drive, porque lo corrí y me apareció

> C:\Users\Alin_\OneDrive\Escritorio\Códigos python\

Gracias

Comment: Tienes que aprender lo básico de tu sistema operativo primero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ejecuta el comando DIR y sabras que archivos y carpetas hay en el directorio en el que estas ademas que ahi mismo te dice

> C:\Users\Alin_\OneDrive\Escritorio\Códigos python

Osea tienes que poner

> cd OneDrive

primero que nada

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, la verdad estoy muy poco relacionada con todo esto. Pero requiero el manejo para mi tesis, te lo agradezco. Escribí lo que me indicaste cd OneDrive, no obstante al querer continuar escribiendo cd Desktop me aparece de nuevo que no encuentra la ruta especificada. Espero puedeas ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Probaste con cd Escritorio? En OneDrive no se llama Desktop lo acabo de comprobar

Comment: Siiii, ya pude ingresar. Muchas gracias :3